# Column is not accessible using sybase

Tags: sas, sap-iq

I'm trying to load a table using SAS but getting an error. This code worked in the past, but since sybase was upgraded it doesn't work with SAS.

```
proc sql;

connect to odbc as db (dsn=sas_xxx uid=&user pwd=&pass insertbuff=2048connection=shared);         

execute(set temporary option escape_character=on) by db;
execute(CREATE TABLE #tomatch (ID int,
DOB int,
NAME_LAST varchar(20),
NAME_FIRST varchar(15),
)) by db;
execute(LOAD TABLE #tomatch (ID, DOB, NAME_LAST, NAME_FIRST)
USING CLIENT FILE "/home/5n0rb/MIGRATE/input/FCRA/&location..csv"
QUOTES ON
ESCAPES OFF
FORMAT BCP
DELIMITED BY ','
ROW DELIMITED BY '\x0a'
SKIP 1) by db;
```

ERROR: CLI execute error: [SAP][ODBC Driver][SAP IQ]Syntax error - Column is not accessible in this context.   --
(dflib/df_Heap.cxx 2763)

Comment: Have you tested the code on the server directly? That would be my first step. If it works there and non via SAS then I'd contact SAS tech support.

Comment: It does work on the server. So I guess its a SAS issue. Thanks

Comment: In that case, it's a SAS Tech Support question to see what's changed.